# Proper way to evaluate models fitted to standardized data

Tags: r, regression

Let's say I fit a regression model to standardized data and then use it to predict out-of-sample data. I evaluate model performance using mean squared error.

I compare this model to another model that simply selects a single predictor and 
calculates mean squared error as: `mean((DV - single predictor)^2)`

The weird thing is that this single predictor model performs better than regression.

What am I missing?

```
    #load data
    data(mtcars)

    #standardize data
    data <- scale(mtcars)

    #matrix for storing results of a 100 replications
    MSE <- matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=100)

    #replicate procedure 100 times
    for(reps in 1:100){

    #divide data into training and test set
    train <- sample(1:nrow(data),nrow(data)*0.5)
    test <- setdiff(1:nrow(data),train)

    train.data <- as.data.frame(data[train,])
    test.data <- as.data.frame(data[test,])

    #fit linear regression and get predictions for test data
    fit <- lm(train.data[,1]~.,data=train.data[,2:ncol(train.data)])
    preds <- suppressWarnings(predict(fit,test.data))

    #calculate mean squared error for regression  
    MSE[reps,1] <- mean((test.data[,1] - preds)^2)

    #calculate mean squared error for the single variable prediction
    MSE[reps,2] <- mean((test.data[,1] - test.data[,5])^2)

    }

    #compare MSE for regression and single variable prediction.    
    colMeans(MSE)
    [1] 1.3268521 0.6020453
```

Comment: A model fitted to standardized data is still regression.

Answer (score 1):

You are operating on the mtcars dataset, which has 32 observations and 11 variables (you are predicting mpg using the other 10 variables):

```
dim(mtcars)
# [1] 32 11
```

In your training/testing set split, you are selecting 16 observations for the training set and 16 for the testing set:

```
train <- sample(1:nrow(data),nrow(data)*0.5)
test <- setdiff(1:nrow(data),train)
```

This means your linear regression models are being fitted with 16 observations and 10 independent variables; this almost certainly leads to significant overfitting to the training data, which is why your out-of-sample MSE is poor for the regression model.

In cases of severely overfitted models, it is not uncommon for the out-of-sample performance of the model to be worse than a simple baseline, which is what is happening here. The data standardization isn't what's causing the issue; model overfitting seems to be the problem here.